# Hyperledger rest api ID field value

Tags: hyperledger

Hyperledger rest API, what's the use of the "ID" field of the payload? Is it a correlation field to keep track of the rest call?

"id":60

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"status":"OK","message":"100"},"id":60}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right `id` field is a correlation field to keep track of the rest call.

As described here,
http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#parameter_structures

> id
>
> This member is REQUIRED.
>
> It MUST be the same as the value of the id
> member in the Request Object.
>
> If there was an error in detecting the
> id in the Request object (e.g. Parse error/Invalid Request), it MUST
> be Null.